# The equation $z\sin z=50$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Let $\mathcal S$ be the set of all the solutions of the equation $$z\sin z=50\space\text{with}\space z\in \mathbb C$$
Try to make a description, as complete as possible, of the set 
$\mathcal S$, in particular prove that $\mathcal S \subset \mathbb R$. What are the elements of $\mathcal S$?

►Hint: We add two ways to prove all root is real:

1) **A school manner** $$\sin z=\frac {e^{iz}-e^{-iz}}{2i}=  \frac{e^{-y+ix}-e^{y-ix}}{2i}=\sin x$$ This implies $z\sin z=(x+iy)\sin x=x\sin x+iy\sin x=50$ hence $y=0$

2) **A little technical**

For $z\sin z=1$,find the number of real roots on the interval
$[-(n+\frac12)\pi, (n+\frac12)\pi]$ and compare to the number of all the roots of this equation in the disk $ | z | < (n + \frac 12)$ $\pi $. Extend then to $50$ instead of $1$

**NOTE**.- This problem is stated (no solution, with just the second hint I gave) in the book "*Recueil de problèmes sur la théorie des fonctions analytiques*", page 222, written by  five Russian authors led by M. Evgrafov. French translation, Editions MIR, 1974.

(The next problem, the same page, is 
*Prove that $\tan z=z$ has only real roots*).

Believed me, these five authors,know their subject very well.

Comment: I got the inclusion (all root is real) and the fact there are infinitely many roots (this is not precisely relevant but the first inclusion I believed that yes it is).

Comment: There are also infinitely many real solutions to $z \sin z = \frac{\pi}{2},$ arranged symmetrically around the origin. Can you find any of the positive ones? In particular, can you numerically estimate the second smallest positive solution?

Comment: Also cannot think of a reason the solutions need to stay real.

Comment: When you have shown all root is real you can see the graph of $x\sin x$ with a calculator and it will be obvious to you there are infinitely many. The problem is answer analitically to the question. It seems more difficult than I have tought.

Comment: @Will Jagy: Yes, all root is real and it is not difficult to prove. Try to find out a non-real one, I think it is impossible.

Comment: I have figured out why the roots should be real. There is no closed form solution using either $50$ or $\pi / 2,$ except in that case I made it so $z = \pi / 2.$ The point is that for a positive integer $n,$ we have $\sin \pi n = 0.$  Consider even, let $x = 2 n \pi + \delta,$ where $2 n \pi > 50$ and $\delta > 0.$ About how big is $\delta?$

Comment: In the previous comment, You may also demand $\delta < 1.$ That is most of the idea, for small $\delta,$ we know that $\sin \delta$ is fairly well approximated by $\delta$ itself.

Comment: See please my edition, Sir

Comment: 1) Your equality in 1. is wrong: take e.g. $y=1$ and $x=0$. 2) I don't see why $z$ should be real. There are complex solutions too (probably not closed-form).

Comment: I don't believe that all roots are real. Note that $z=2.484 + 3.2055i$ is an approximate solution.

Comment: @MarkMcClure And this solution corresponds to the first (left) intersection in the figure below.

Comment: Read, please, mi NOTE in a new edit.

Comment: @MarkMcClure: for all equation in $\mathbb R$ (exceptional cases maybe) all root has a non-countable infinity of "approximations"

Comment: @Ataulfo I'm fairly certain that there are 32 non-zero roots. After seeing anderstood's post, do you believe otherwise? Your note on $\tan(z)=z$ refers to an entirely different equation.

Comment: @MarkMcClure Why 32? (and I guess you mean non-_real_ roots).

Comment: @anderstood Yes, my bad - non-real. I just left a comment on your post indicating how I arrived at the 32.

Comment: @Ataulfo It's pretty clear to me now that you are asking about two totally different equations: $z\sin(z)=50$ and $\tan(z)=z$. The first has 32 non-real roots in the disk of radius 50 and only real roots outside while the second has only real roots. Possibly, the two equations are related as the derivative of the first yields something very much like the second.

Comment: In any event, the latter equation can certainly be tackled using the argument principle to show that $f(z)=\tan(z)-z$ has $2n+1$ in the disk of radius $(n+1/2)\pi$. The second can probably be tackled in a similar manner, though I was only able to compute the resulting integral numerically. Possibly, the computation could be simplified using the concept of a winding number.

Comment: Since there's two questions and it's really not clear which one you're after, I've downvoted andvoted to close as unclear. I suggest you edit to focus on one equation or the other. You can always open a new question on the other equation. If the point is to use one to help with the other, you should make *that* clear then.

Comment: I do believe that the five guys are very good but I still don't believe you when you state that $e^z+e^\overline z=2i\sin(x)$...

Comment: This school manner is not the problem, dear friend. The problem is that the "technical hint" is given by the specialists which adds to the idea that their proposition is true. The problem is "all the roots are real" and the only way to deny this is either, show a non-real root or to prove the existence of non-real roots.

Comment: @MarkMcClure: the equation $\tan (z)=z$ is not at all another posted question (it was named just for information giving another case of all root is real)

Comment: @anderstood: that definition is given by   the american mathematician Tom Mike Apostol in his Mathematical analysis. It is certainly equivalent to the other with hyperbolics

Comment: @Ataulfo Definition 1.58 on page 24 of Apostol's *Mathematical Analysis* 2nd edition states the well known definition of the sine function in the complex domain: $\sin(z)=(e^{iz}-e^{-iz})/(2i)$. It does *not* state that $\sin(z)=\sin(x)$ when $z=x+iy$, as you have stated and crucially used in your "proof" that the roots of $z\sin(z)=50$ are real. Also, I never stated that you *posted* two questions on two equations. My impression is that you have conflated two questions from your text creating one confused question here, resulting in the incorrect claim that $z\sin(z)=50$ has only real roots.

Comment: @Ataulfo I don't see how it could be equivalent if one does not depend on $y$ while the other does.

Comment: @Ataulfo I don't know how well-versed the authors are in complex analysis, but that doesn't matter much. Even experts make mistakes sometimes, and the authors (or the translator[s]) made a mistake here. There are non-real solutions of $z\sin z = 50$. You can use the minimum modulus principle to see that one is close to the approximate solution mentioned by Mark McClure above.

Comment: @MarkMcClure: a "scholar" proof can be wrong. I think the only way to prove the authors are made a mistake is to use their HINT and show it is not appropriate or insufficient. And, of course, exhibit a non-real solution. Regards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, let's take a look at the graph of $y=x\sin(x)$ together with $y=50$, which makes it clear that there are no real roots for $|x|<50$.

[image]

Next, let's pull out the power of Mathematica to search for all roots with absolute value less than 80.

```
z /. NSolve[z*Sin[z] == 50 && Abs[z] < 80, z];

(* Out:
{-45.5764 + 0.437537 I, -45.5764 - 0.437537 I, -39.2996 - 0.722313 I, 
 -39.2996 + 0.722313 I, -33.026 - 0.974674 I, -33.026 + 0.974674 I, 
 -26.7582 - 1.23677 I, -26.7582 + 1.23677 I, -20.5024 - 1.53721 I, 
 -20.5024 + 1.53721 I, -14.2765 - 1.91703 I, -14.2765 + 1.91703 I, 
 -8.15089 - 2.45747 I, -8.15089 + 2.45747 I, -2.48394 - 3.20556 I, 
 -2.48394 + 3.20556 I, 2.48394 - 3.20556 I, 2.48394 + 3.20556 I, 
 8.15089 - 2.45747 I, 8.15089 + 2.45747 I, 14.2765 - 1.91703 I, 
 14.2765 + 1.91703 I, 20.5024 - 1.53721 I, 20.5024 + 1.53721 I, 
 26.7582 - 1.23677 I, 26.7582 + 1.23677 I, 33.026 + 0.974674 I, 
 33.026 - 0.974674 I, 39.2996 - 0.722313 I, 39.2996 + 0.722313 I, 
 45.5764 - 0.437537 I, 45.5764 + 0.437537 I,
 51.5875, 52.1226, 57.5999, 58.67, 63.7338, 65.0976, 
 69.9119, 71.482, 76.1149, 77.8423}
 *)
```

It appears, contrary to the assertion in the question, that there are 32 non-real roots. There are also a number of real roots that agree with our plot above.

When using mathematical software, however, it always wise to double check by approaching the problem from multiple angles, particularly when there is an assertion contrary to our results. One geometric check (suggested by the first answer to this question) is sketch contour plots of the real and imaginary parts of the equation, namely:

\begin{align}
x \sin (x) \cosh (y)-y \cos (x) \sinh (y) &= 50 \\
x \cos (x) \sinh (y)+y \sin (x) \cosh (y) &= 0.
\end{align}

If we plot those contours together with the points generated by the `NSolve` command above, we get the following picture:

[image]

The points of intersection of these contours are exactly the solutions we seek and they agree exactly with those solutions returned by `NSolve`, which are the black dots in the figure. The agreement of these two different approaches seems quite compelling. Let us examine one more approach, however, using the argument principle. As stated on [it's Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_principle), the argument principle states that if $f(z)$ is a meromorphic function inside and on some closed contour $C$, and $f$ has no zeros or poles on $C$, then
$$N-P = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \oint_C \frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}dz,$$
where $N$ is the number of roots of $f$ inside $C$ and $P$ is the number of poles inside $C$. As our function has no poles, the integral represents just the number of roots.

Now, for this problem, the function $f$ is $f(z)=z\sin(z)-50$ and the integrand is
$$\frac{f'(z)}{f(z)} = \frac{\sin (z)+z \cos (z)}{z \sin (z)-50}.$$

Parameterizing the circle of radius $50$ to translate the integral to a regular integral in terms of $t$ we get

$$\frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{\left(\sin \left(50 e^{i t}\right)+
 50 e^{it} \cos \left(50 e^{i t}\right)\right)}{50 e^{i t} \sin
   \left(50 e^{i t}\right) - 50}50 i e^{i t} dt. $$

Any decent numerical integrator should be able to evaluate this to get 32. For example, you can do it online using [Mathematica via WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=NIntegrate[%28%2850*I%29*E%5E%28I*t%29*%2850*E%5E%28I*t%29*Cos[50*E%5E%28I*t%29]+%2B+Sin[50*E%5E%28I*t%29]%29%29%2F%28-50+%2B+50*E%5E%28I*t%29*Sin[50*E%5E%28I*t%29]%29%2C+%7Bt%2C+0%2C+2*Pi%7D]%2F%282Pi*I%29) or using [SciPy via the sage cell server](http://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJx1kE0OwiAQhfdNeodZAqJWk25MPIsh7dTQtIBTmujtBfwrGlnBvPnmPaYjO4KZR3cDPTpLHvDqJEzaSGjsJIFQDTJo6izB6bLoIjA12t022ng8k_L4Qi-zasuixQ6ekmmZ54eygHAI_UwG6qoXrK5EsGG7Xngugk1W4Kvgnlf4577N4Z_WdV3xR4aY_OQU-ZgBshBRYsuMTyR-8w8SpW8kORBO8-AfizohkSU4pk2wdwAJlYS9cDowySIoiUmPjHknWDKNHd2AV5b5LQaFpez72HoHpvKTpw==&lang=sage).

Finally, if we understand how to interpret the argument principle geometrically, we obtain a qualitative approach to the problem - one that might be what the original authors intended. The integrand $f'(z)/f(z)$ has a simple anti-derivative, namely $\log(f(z))$. In light of [the residue theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_theorem), this can be interpreted as the number of times $f(C)$ winds about the origin. Here are the images of the circle of radius $k$ under the map $f(z)=z\sin(z)-k$ for $k=1$, $k=4$ and $k=50$.

[image]

Note that these paths are traced out *twice*, since $f$ is an even function. Thus, for $k=4$, we should have four complex roots, since the path winds around the origin two times. For $k=1$ we have no complex roots. For $k=50$, it's quite hard to tell, since the scale of the axes are of the order $10^{23}$. Nonetheless, the path winds around the origin 16 times yielding the 32 roots of the function.

Comment: Then the mistake was mine and not of the authors because the original problem was with $z\sin ( z)=k$ with $k = 1$. Based on your first graph, I altered this constant giving the value $k = 50$. Your answer is highly successful, and provides a great lesson in Math. Very thankful.

Answer (score 1):

Posing $z=x+iy$, take the real and imaginary parts of $z\sin(z)=50$:

$$x \sin (x) \cosh (y)-y \cos (x) \sinh (y)=50 \quad \text{and}\quad x \cos (x) \sinh (y)+y \sin (x) \cosh (y)=0$$

Note that both equations are even in $x$ and $y$ so the investigation can be restricted to $x,y>0$.

The real solutions correspond to $y=0$, i.e. $x\sin(x)=50$ (and $0=0$). Necessarily, $|x|\geq  50$ and it is clear that there is an infinity of solutions (oscillating function between $|x|>50$ and $-|x|<0<50$, and continuous).

But there are also solutions for $y\neq 0$. You may be able to prove it using the intermediate value theorem as the two functions are continuous.

Here is a illustration of the solutions of each equation (the solutions of $z\sin(z)$ correspond to the intersections):

[image]

Comment: If there are non-real solutions, then give me just one. See the NOTE in the edition ,please.

Comment: @Ataulfo Mark McClure gave you an approximation of a non-real solution: $z=2.484+3.2055i$ which perfectly matches with my independent developments. I managed to get more accurate approximate (down to machine precision) with Mathematica but I did not keep the file. Anyway, it does not change the results of my answer. Maybe there's a mistake in the translation.

Comment: @anderstood The mistake in the translation from the book to this site. Taking a look at the latest edit to the question, it's clear that the the book states that the different (though possibly related) equation $\tan(z)=z$ has only real solutions. I think that's not particularly hard to show by applying the argument principle to show that $f(z)=\tan(z)-z$ has $2n+1$ roots in the disk of radius $(n+1/2)\pi$. Similarly I can certainly show that $z\sin(z)=50$ has 32 roots in the disk of radius 50 using a numerical integral. Possibly there's a slick way to use that latter result to get the former.

Comment: No mistake in the translation. This problem was accompanied by the "A little technical" hint 2) I have added to the post.